# Why do I get a gdal_translate error when creating ecw from tif

Tags: ecw, gdal-translate

I have python 2.7 and the latest gdal 32bit core with also GDAL-1.10.1.win32-py2.7.msi and the ecw plugin on windows xp. I have checked that the ecw plugin works by checking the installed formats with gdalinfo --formats. When I try a simple tif to ecw translation I get this error:

```
Input file size is 157, 157
0ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this 
format
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the ECW 4.x driver package, this is expected behaviour.

From http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html

> The ECW 4.x SDK from ERDAS is only free for image decompression. To
>   compress images it is necessary to build with the read/write SDK and
>   to provide an OEM licensing key at runtime which may be purchased from
>   ERDAS.

Options are ECW 3.3 SDK if you can still find it, or purchasing the required license and rebuilding.

Comment: shame....is there another format which is as good in order to reduce the s file sizes of tifs?

Comment: JPEG2000 would be worth a try for full colour. If you're trying something that was originally a vector, perhaps convert that to PDF directly. Performance and size depends on your data - you'd have to try it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manpage http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html, you need to buy a licence from ERDAS to create ecw files with the current driver.

Only the old ECW 3.3 SDK can compress files up to 500MB for free.